# Java subprocess extra output to console

Tags: java, io, processbuilder

I've written a java-program that starts sub-processes(through the `ProcessBuilder`) and treats their I/O (`Process.getInputStream(),Process.getErrorStream(),Process.getOutputStream()`) streams in different threads.

My java-program works as a server and I don't want extra output to the console from sub-processes and
in the IDE's console it works fine, but if I try to run the program `java -jar ...` from the windows or linux console, the sub-process writes output to my program and also to the console.

P.S. I execute Python script files from java, for example my python script script prints a test string "Hello World" 1000 times.
My program treats it fine, but I see it's output also in the console.

Is there some kind of "console" that I need to detach from the process somehow?

**UPDATE:**

Here I get a ProcessBuilder for running the python(I pass the directory of the script as a parameter):

```
private ProcessBuilder getBuilder(File directory) {
    return new ProcessBuilder("python", "-u").directory(directory);
}
```

Here I start a Process from the builder and return it to further treatment(
I pass the directory of the script and args to the script):

```
 public Process execute(Path dir, String... args) {
    if (!Files.exists(dir) || !Files.isDirectory(dir))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Provided path " + dir + " is not a directory or doesn't exist");
    ProcessBuilder builder = getBuilder(dir.toFile());
    if (args.length > 0) {
        builder.command().addAll(Arrays.asList(args));
    }
    try {
        return builder.start();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is a test dumb script:

```
i=0;
while True:
    if i%1000000==0:
        print ('Hello, world!')
    i+=1
```

I don't know if there a sence to post my stream handlers because they look like  standard gobblers that was in other topics but they read from process out/error to the queue and get input from another queue and java program treats queues and has no output to console except logger messages.

But it seems the sub-process itself writes to the console, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I think, you need to show your Java code so folks can have an idea as what you are talking about.

Comment: As said: Show your Java code (at least the relevant parts). Did you properly set up [`redirectOutput()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectInput%28java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect%29) and [`redirectError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectError%28java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect%29)?

Comment: @dhke I get the Process object and then take it's IO through the process.getOutputStream(), process.getInputStream(), process.getErrorStrem();

Comment: @dhke As I understand by default Redirect is PIPE and that means that I can use get... methods to get I/O from the process am I right? I just get streams and do not redirect anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find out how to do it programmaticaly.
The only way that helps me is to redirect the output to /dev/null when I start the jar file.
It's quite appropriate, because I also get the output by network to the client.